# Universal change of variable $t = \tan(\frac{\theta}{2})$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, convergence-divergence

In many textbooks, the authors explain, without rigorous justification, we could always solve a trigonometric integral in using the change of variable $t = \tan(\frac{\theta}{2})$. Is there anyone could explain rigorously why is it true?

Comment: Not *any* trigonometic integral, but say the integral of $G(\sin\theta,\cos\theta)$ where $G(x,y)$ is a rational function. And it is only "in principle," since we end up integrating $H(t)$ where $H$ is a rational function. If $H$ is complicated, the integration may be painful.

Answer (score 1):

$\sin\theta$, $\cos\theta$ and $\tan\theta$ are rational functions of $\tan(\theta/2)$. Let $t=\tan(\theta/2)$, we have $$\sin\theta=\frac{2t}{1+t^2},$$ $$\cos\theta=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2},$$ and $$\tan\theta=\frac{2t}{1-t^2}.$$

As pointed out by @SpinningAtInfinity, if $G$ is a rational function w.r.t. trigonometric functions of $\theta,$ it can be expressed as a rational function of $t.$ Furthermore $$d\theta=\frac{2dt}{1+t^2}.$$ Using this change of variable, we only need to solve a rational integral, which always has an antiderivative.